# Signal strength measurements of Mobile Networks in iOS and/or Android?

Tags: iphone, android, networking, ios4

Can you get signal strength measurements of Mobile Networks in iOS and/or Android?

On developer.apple.com I have found CoreWLANWirelessManager sample code for OSX, that shows how to get measurements for WiFi networks.

Answer (score 2):

For Android, what about [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)?